# OnceAsync: run f# async function exactly once

Tags: asynchronous, f#

I'm trying to write a function (OnceAsync f) that ensures that an async function is run only once on a server (i.e. a multi-threaded environment). I thought it would be easy, but it became complicated quickly (locks, busy waits!!)

This is my solution, but I think it's over-engineered; there must be a better way.  This should work in FSI:

```
let locked_counter init =
    let c = ref init
    fun x -> lock c <| fun () -> 
        c := !c + x
        !c
let wait_until finished = async {  
    while not(finished()) do
        do! Async.Sleep(1000) 
}

let OnceAsync f = 
    // - ensure that the async function, f, is only called once
    // - this function always returns the value, f()
    let mutable res = None
    let lock_inc = locked_counter 0

    async {
        let count = lock_inc 1

        match res, count with
        | None, 1 ->    // 1st run
            let! r = f
            res <- Some r
        | None, _ ->    // nth run, wait for 1st run to finish
            do! wait_until (fun() -> res.IsSome)
        | _ -> ()       // 1st run done, return result

        return res.Value
    }
```

You can use this code to test if OnceAsync is correct:

```
let test() =
    let mutable count = 0

    let initUser id = async {
        do! Async.Sleep 1000 // simulate work
        count <- count + 1
        return count
    }

    //let fmem1 = (initUser "1234")
    let fmem1 = OnceAsync (initUser "1234")

    async {
        let ps = Seq.init 20 (fun i -> fmem1)
        let! rs = ps |> Async.Parallel
        printfn "rs = %A" rs     // outputs: [|1; 1; 1; 1; 1; ....; 1|]
    }

test() |> Async.Start
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it fits, the simplest approach overall would be to use `Async.StartChild`.  Unlike your solution it causes the function to run even if the result is never actually used though, e.g. in the `Seq.init 0` case.

```
//let fmem1 = OnceAsync (initUser "1234")

async {
  let! fmem1 = Async.StartChild (initUser "1234")
  let ps = Seq.init 20 (fun i -> fmem1)
  let! rs = ps |> Async.Parallel
  printfn "rs = %A" rs     // outputs: [|1; 1; 1; 1; 1; ....; 1|]
} |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

The simplest approach most similar to yours would be to use a `TaskCompletionSource` as follows:

```
let OnceAsync f = 
  let count = ref 0
  let tcs = TaskCompletionSource<_>()
  async {
    if Interlocked.Increment(count) = 1 then
      let! r = f
      tcs.SetResult r
    return! Async.AwaitTask tcs.Task
  }
```

A more functional approach would use a `MailboxProcessor` and have it cache the result after the first run, and respond with it to all subsequent requests.

```
let OnceAsync f = 
  let handler (agent: MailboxProcessor<AsyncReplyChannel<_>>) =
    let rec run resultOpt =
      async {
        let! chan = agent.Receive()
        let! result = 
          match resultOpt with
          | None -> f
          | Some result -> async.Return result
        chan.Reply result
        return! run (Some result)
      }
    run None
  let mbp = MailboxProcessor.Start handler
  async { return! mbp.PostAndAsyncReply id }
```

Comment: Nice!! I was looking to get away from locks and waits, but this is much better than what I have.

Comment: @Ray I added a `MailboxProcessor` sample, but IIRC it does use locks under the hood, so I don't know if you can get away from them completely.

Comment: Looks like I can't get away from locks. The TaskCompletionSource solution works. I can't use Interlocked.Increment though; I'll just make my own version.